# Web UserControl extending custom class which extend Page Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance, user-controls

I am creating an application on ASP.NET 3.5. In my application I am creating a single class that manages SEssion information, so all the `Web form (.aspx) pages` and `User Controls (.ascx) pages` will extend my custom class to access the session information.

Here is my custom class

```
public class ManageSession<T> : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const string SESSION_NAME = "NewSession";

    public T SessionData 
    {
        get
        {
            T sessionImp = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Session[SESSION_NAME],typeof(T));
            if (sessionImp == null )
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");

                return sessionImp;
        }
        set
        {
            Session[SESSION_NAME] = value;
        }
    }

    public T ViewStateData
    {
        get
        {
            T sessionImp = (T)Convert.ChangeType(ViewState[SESSION_NAME], typeof(T));                
            return sessionImp;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState[SESSION_NAME] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

now I have created a BasePage class which I am extending on every page class.

```
public class BasePage :  ManageSession<UserSession>
{

}
```

On my `Default.aspx` page that's how I am extending the BasePage class to use the Session information.

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
    this.SessionData             // till here everything is fine, I am able to access SessionData Property of my MySession<> class.
}
```

But when I try to extend BasePage class in UserControl, I get an error and unable to extend the BasePage class for UserControl.

```
// This MyControl is basically a Web User Control, Initially extended from System.Web.UI.UserControl     
public partial class MyControl: BasePage
{  }
```

When I execute the application, this is what error I am getting

> 'MyControls' is not allowed here because it does not extend class
>   'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

How can I use my `BasePage` class for both ASPX pages and UserCOntrols as well?? or please guide me with any other solution?

Comment: @Handoko.Chen thanks for editing.

Comment: Why would you want to use a `BasePage` class as the parent class for user controls? Wouldn't an interface be more suitable?

Comment: If I create an interface and define Properties as SessionData and ViewStateDate. From my default and USerControl class I have to implement that interface. I guess it will not work, My thoughts
Would you please provide little implementation with interface?